# Cppcheck with mutex locking / unlocking

Tags: mutex, cppcheck

Is there a way that Cppcheck checks the mutex locking / unlocking functionalities?

An example (with an error):

```
void foo() {
    mutex_lock();
    if (condition) { // condition is true
        return;
    }
    mutex_unlock();
}
```

Is there a way Cppcheck can detect such a problem (the mutex stays locked)?

Answer (score 0):

No, checking locking / unlocking functionalities is currently not supported.

It seems like you also asked the question in the Cppcheck forum where there is already feedback:
https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/development/thread/a7b82c3e/

The best workaround that can currently be used is described in Daniel Marjamäki's answer:
https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/development/thread/a7b82c3e/#f237
It suggests to use wrapper functions and the allocation / deallocation checks that are already supported by Cppcheck.

Comment: Starting with Cppcheck 2.2 there are some std::mutex-related checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect this error using the PVS-Studio analyzer. A [V1020](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v1020/) diagnostic will be issued for this code: V1020 The function exited without calling the 'mutex_unlock' function. Check lines: 20, 18. test.cpp.

This is an empirical diagnostic which tries to figure out the way the code works based on functions names.